# How to see all options configurable by "defaults write ..."

Tags: customization, defaults

Many Mac apps have "hidden" configurable options that can be modified in Terminal by using the `defaults write ...` command. This is straightforward to do if you know the name of the option that you want to configure ahead of time.

Is a list of values that each application actually uses tucked away somewhere in a master config file?

How do people discover these options without a list of all configurable options for a given Application?